# Redux Thunk synchronous actions are not synchronous

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using React/Redux for an app I'm building and I'm trying to implement an action to log out the user. My app has artifacts that can be edited. I want my app to first save the artifact, then log out the user, which will clear the store. I've implemented this as follows using Redux Thunk:

```
export function logoutUser(artifact) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(saveArtifact(artifact))
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(requestLogout());
        return axios.get(`${API_BASE}/auth/logout`)
          .then(() => dispatch(logoutSuccess()))
          .catch(error => dispatch(logoutFailure(error)));
      });
  };
}
```

I would expect this to save the artifact and only when it's saved, log the user out. My save action calls another action itself which loads the artifacts after they're saved, but that shouldn't matter. It should return a promise and only then move on to logging out the user.

However, this is not what is happening. For some reason, I am getting multiple calls to save the artifact (verified they are coming from this function) and then the calls happen asynchronously, so that loading the artifacts is last, and thus my redux store is not getting cleared upon logout.

Would love if someone could provide some insight into why this is happening and how I can fix it.

#### Additional info:

I am clearing the redux store in my root reducer as follows:

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  let newState = state;
  if (action.type === types.LOGOUT_SUCCESS) {
    newState = undefined;
  }

  return appReducer(newState, action);
};
```

I am saving the artifacts as follows:

```
function sendSaveArtifactRequest(artifact) {
  if (artifact._id == null) {
    const artifactWithoutId = _.omit(artifact, ['_id']);
    return axios.post(`${API_BASE}/artifacts`, artifactWithoutId)
      .then(result => result.data);
  }

  return axios.put(`${API_BASE}/artifacts`, artifact).then(() => artifact);
}

export function saveArtifact(artifact) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestSaveArtifact());

    return sendSaveArtifactRequest(artifact)
      .then(data => dispatch(saveArtifactSuccess(data)))
      .catch(error => dispatch(saveArtifactFailure(error)))
      .then(() => dispatch(loadArtifacts()));
  };
}
```

I am loading artifacts as follows:

```
function sendArtifactsRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(`${API_BASE}/artifacts`)
      .then(result => resolve(result.data))
      .catch(error => reject(error));
  });
}

export function loadArtifacts() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestArtifacts());

    return sendArtifactsRequest()
      .then(data => dispatch(loadArtifactsSuccess(data)))
      .catch(error => dispatch(loadArtifactsFailure(error)));
  };
}
```

Comment: how you are clearing redux store?

Comment: Added that info to my post, which was based off this post: https://netbasal.com/how-to-secure-your-users-data-after-logout-in-redux-30468c6848e8

Comment: where are you dispatching clearing redux state action ?

Comment: There is no redux action for that. If you look at the link I posted it explains what is happening. In my case, the root reducer looks to see if the `LOGOUT_SUCCESS` action comes through, and if so, resets the state.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `saveArtifact`?

Comment: Added `saveArtifact` and `loadArtifacts` actions to my post.

Comment: @NorandaBrown I have added a detailed explanation as I have faced similar problem a little while ago

Comment: `saveArtifact` function does not return a promise. Also, I'm not quite sure how practical using action creators like that. Better change your logic maybe? If there is a separate logout option than just use one simple action creator for this. Do not trigger any dispatch before this. If saving artifacts should trigger a logut, do this in the saving action creator. For example first, save the artifact with a standard call, then use promise here. If successful, dispatch the logout, if not do another thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue, there are multiple chained promises in your `saveArtifact` action. What is happening in your case, after `sendSaveArtifactRequest` promise resolution you dispatch `requestLogout` and upon it's success you clear redux state. But on the other side there are still pending promises you're not waiting for their resolution in `logoutUser` action. When you clear redux store you pending promise gets resolved and the update redux state again. 
You can do two things here:

- use `Promise.all().then()` while dispatching `saveArtifact` then dispatch logout action.
- You can Logout user in `loadArtifacts` action but I'm not sure exact use case, maybe this doesn't fit with your app requirement. but it will always called when artifacts are loaded.

Most importantly, please integrate **Redux DevTools** in your app so you can track in which sequence actions are dispatched.

in your `store.js`

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './reducers';

const enhancer = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
);

export default createStore(rootReducer, enhancer);
```

`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I unfortunately can't chain logging out onto saving or loading the artifacts, since I use them elsewhere. With regard to using `Promise.all()`, this also doesn't help as I'm not returning more than one promise. I am chaining promises as follows: `saveArtifact` > `loadArtifacts` > `logoutUser`, with only one promise being returned at a time before `.then()` is called. That's really my question here. Why aren't they being chained correctly? And why is `saveArtifact` being called more than once?